# Disabling onClick until int = something

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int foulCounterA = 0;
int scoreOnePointTeamA = 0;
int periodCount = 0;
private TextView tv1;
private TextView period;
private Button startbtn, cancelbtn;
private ToggleButton togbtn;
private boolean isPaused = false;
private boolean isCanceled = false;
private long remainingTime = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    period = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.period_number);
    startbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
    cancelbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);
    togbtn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togBtn);

    cancelbtn.setEnabled(false);
    togbtn.setEnabled(false);

    startbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            foulCounterA = 0;
            foulCounterB = 0;
            displayForTeamAFoul(foulCounterA);
            displayForTeamBFoul(foulCounterB);

            if (periodCount < 3)
                periodCount = periodCount + 1;
            else periodCount = 4;
            period.setText("Period " + periodCount);

            startbtn.setEnabled(false);
            cancelbtn.setEnabled(true);
            togbtn.setEnabled(true);

            isPaused = false;
            isCanceled = false;

            long millisInFuture = 20000; /////20sec
            long countDownInterval = 1000; /////1sec
            new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    if (isPaused || isCanceled) {
                        cancel();
                    } else {
                        tv1.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                        remainingTime = millisUntilFinished;
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {

                    startbtn.setEnabled(true);
                    togbtn.setEnabled(false);

                    if (periodCount < 4)
                        tv1.setText("Times up!");
                    else tv1.setText("Game Over!");
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });

    togbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (togbtn.isChecked()) {
                isPaused = true;
            } else {
                isPaused = false;
                long millisInFuture = remainingTime;
                long countDownInterval = 1000; /////1sec
                new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        if (isPaused || isCanceled) {
                            cancel();
                        } else {
                            tv1.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                            remainingTime = millisUntilFinished;
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {

                        startbtn.setEnabled(true);
                        togbtn.setEnabled(false);

                        if (periodCount < 4)
                            tv1.setText("Times up!");
                        else tv1.setText("Game Over!");

                    }
                }.start();
            }
        }
    });

    cancelbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            isCanceled = true;
            period.setText("Period");
            tv1.setText("Timer");
            startbtn.setEnabled(true);
            togbtn.setEnabled(false);
            cancelbtn.setEnabled(false);

            foulCounterA = 0;
            foulCounterB = 0;
            periodCount = 0;
            displayForTeamAFoul(foulCounterA);
            displayForTeamBFoul(foulCounterB);
        }
    });
}

public void onePointForTeamA(View v) {
    scoreTeamA = scoreTeamA + 1;
    scoreOnePointTeamA = scoreOnePointTeamA + 1;
    displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);
    displayForTeamAOnePoint(scoreOnePointTeamA);
}

public void foulCountForTeamA(View v) {
    if (foulCounterA < 5)
        foulCounterA = foulCounterA + 1;
    else
        foulCounterA = 5;
    displayForTeamAFoul(foulCounterA);
}

public void displayForTeamAOnePoint(int score) {
    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_a_score_1_point);
    scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
}

public void displayForTeamAFoul(int score) {
    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_a_foul);
    scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
}

}
```

I wanted to make the java code as simple as I can so I've just added the lines for my question. What I'm trying to do is

`android:onClick="onePointForTeamA"`make this button only clickable when `foulCounterA = 5` 
Failed to add `if (foulCounterA = 5);` inside `public void foulCountForTeamA(View v) {`

It gave me an error that way. Says `required: boolean, found: int.`

What should I do with the code? Any help will be appreeciated

Comment: You should look at a very basic java tutorial about operators: [Operators - 
The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) - And especially pay attention to the difference between the `assignment` and `equality` operators.

Comment: Just add that condition before the onClickListener which will only react if your condition is successful. Plus = is used when assigning values and == is used when comparing values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your concrete question, the syntax of if (foulCounterA = 5); is wrong, because the equation check is have to made by == operator.

So the correct syntax would be  if (foulCounterA == 5);

As @OH GOD SPIDERS wrote in the comment, you should check the basics of java operators.

Also I recommend You to search for the answer before asking a new question.

Comment: as I'm really new to the development it was really hard for me to search without knowing the issue so couldn't really know what the problem was and how to do proper search. Ty for the help and I'll check as @OH GOD SPIDERS mentioned above aswell.